# Legality of Recording

Tags: canada, privacy, recording

Is it legal for someone to record my crotch area that is fully clothed (e.g. wearing pants and undergarment not visible) and/or my face in a public place in Canada where there is no "reasonable expectation of privacy" (e.g. under or over a table in a public library)?

What about my buttocks area when I am walking (also fully clothed) in a public place (e.g. on the streets)?

---

In my opinion, it is not ethical for him to do this to me but it seems legal since it is not technically upskirting nor downblousing and I have not seen videos online of it yet.

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly unlawful if his actions constitute [harassment](http://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/C-46/section-264.html) if you find them threatening. Presumably you do or you wouldn't ask the question.

Notwithstanding, this is extremely creepy and inappropriate behavior and needs to stop.

I can't give you advice on how to handle it because it depends on your level of conflict tolerance and the support you have available.

Comment: Local statutes might also prohibit it under the term "Stalking."